# ckeditor 4 fckeditor filemanager intergrate

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm trying to intergrate the fckeditor filemanager into the newest ckeditor. I'm following a little tutorial you can find here
`http://www.mixedwaves.com/2010/02/integrating-fckeditor-filemanager-in-ckeditor/`

I added the replace links as suggested. 
and changed my config.php to enable the filemanager.

The problem is i get an error in `ckeditor.js` on `line 252`
the error is 
`TypeError: b is undefined`

what is causing this?

**EDIT**
when i do: `document.write(b.value);`
i get the right output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for the question is very simple:)
**give your textarea an ID**

Old:
`<div id='ckeditor_div' style='display:none;'><textarea  class='ckeditor' style='display:inline-block;' name='tooltip_info'>". $tooltip['tip'] ."</textarea></div>`

New:
`<div id='ckeditor_div' style='display:none;'><textarea id='ckeditor' class='ckeditor' style='display:inline-block;' name='tooltip_info'>". $tooltip['tip'] ."</textarea></div>`

as you can see i added `id='ckeditor'` in the `textarea`

Answer (score 0):

This error also appears when you more than one instance of CkEditor trying to use the same element. Just make sure you aren't using " CKEDITOR.replace " more than once on the same element. In my case, I had to remove that line from the config.js